# Gmail API in chrome extension won't send an email

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I'm trying to create my first chrome extension that when some event happends it will send an email to my own gmail account using gmail API.

I'm trying to get the sendMessage function to work but it seems like the message.sent won't finish successfuly.
any suggestions what can be done?

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "MysteryScanner",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "simple MysteryScanner notifier",
    "background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
      },
    "permissions": [
         "contextMenus",
         "activeTab",
         "<all_urls>",
         "identity",
         "*://*.google.com/*"
       ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "web_accessible_resources":  ["js/background.js", "js/counterstring.js", "js/base64.js"],
    "oauth2": {
      "client_id": "<my_client_id>",
      "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
      ]
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken(
    {'interactive': true},
    function(){
      //load Google's javascript client libraries
        window.gapi_onload = authorize;
        loadScript('https://apis.google.com/js/client.js');
    }
);

function loadScript(url){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState !== 4) {
            return;
        }

        if(request.status !== 200){
            return;
        }

    eval(request.responseText);
    };

    request.open('GET', url);
    request.send();
}

function authorize(){
  gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
            client_id: '<my_client_id>',
            immediate: true,
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'
        },
        function(){
          gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', gmailAPILoaded);
        }
    );
}

function gmailAPILoaded(){
    gmail = gapi.client.gmail;
}

function notifyNewInput(input){
    console.log("Found new input!");
    sendMessage(gapi.auth, "my_email@gmail.com", "my_email@gmail.com", "test_subject", "test contennttt");
}

function sendMessage(auth, from, to, subject, content) {
    
    encodedEmail = "RnJvbTogTGlvciBEaWFtYW50IDxkaWFtbGlvckBnbWFpbC5jb20+ClRvOiBMaW9yIERpYW1hbnQgPGRpYW1saW9yQGdtYWlsLmNvbT4KU3ViamVjdDogU2F5aW5nIEhlbGxvCgpUaGlzIGlzIGEgbWVzc2FnZSBqdXN0IHRvIHNheSBoZWxsby4KU28sICJIZWxsbyIu"
    var request = gmail.users.messages.send({
      'resource': {
        'raw': encodedEmail,
        "payload": {
            "headers": [
              {
                "name": "From",
                'value': "my_email@gmail.com"
              },
              {
                'name': "To",
                'value': "my_email@gmail.com"
              }
            ]
      }
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err != null)
            console.log(err);
      console.log('result:', result);
    }});
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the issue? Is there any error displayed in the console? Is the OAuth authorization successful? Could you explain where the `encodedEmail` variable comes from and if it is a well formed [`base64url encoded string`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#resource:-message)?